# TypeScript nested generic definition not working with function return

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, zod

I created stackblitz example for convenient reading and fixing (I hope)

https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-a8d4nq?file=index.ts

I want to create interface that describing validation with zod library and pass types into another function params.

It's basic setup, I creating `zodObject` function for validation and simple request function

```
import * as _zod from 'zod';

export const zodObject = <T extends _zod.ZodRawShape>(shape: T) => {
  const obj = _zod.object(shape);

  return (data: any): _zod.infer<_zod.ZodObject<T>> => {
    try {
      return obj.parse(data);
    } catch (e) {
      throw e;
    }
  };
};

const request = <Q extends unknown = unknown>(options: {
  queryValidate(data: any): Q;
  handler(params: { query: Q }): any;
}) => {
  // Here will be some express function for sending
  return options;
};
```

In first variant everything is okay but I want to use it as generic function, so I tried second variant and it's didn't work with any of my ideas.

```
request({
  queryValidate: (query) =>
    zodObject({
      email: _zod.string().min(1).email(),
    })(query),
  handler({ query }) {
    return query.email;
  },
});

request({
  queryValidate: zodObject({
    email: _zod.string().email(),
  }),
  handler({ query }) {
    return query.email;
  },
});
```